# Given one expression, find value of another expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + z^{1/3} = 0$

Find value of $(x + y + z)^3$

The final answer seems to be $0$ as well. I can't even seem to find a way to start.

Comment: Yep, if you let $x=y=z=0$, then I bet you'll get all sorts of equations that evaluate to $0$...pretty sure you're missing some context bro.

Comment: If $x=8$, $y=z=-1$, then the equation is satisfied but the sum is $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $27xyz$. Lemma- If $a+b+c=0$, then $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$. Use this result once and then cube the equation you get, you will get the answer.